# Add conditional stylesheet CSS for internet explorer only

Tags: 7, theming

The following methods can be used to add CSS for specific versions of IE:

1. Paste the code into html.tpl.php:

   `<!--[if lt IE 9]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="/sites/all/themes/mytheme/less/ie.css"><![endif]-->`
2. Make use of the plugin [Conditional Styles](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles)
3. Use drupal_add_css() function

I have always used option #1 above, and adding yet another plugin for something so simple seemed crazy. **BUT** working with LESS and calling in statically means the file does not get processed by the LESS pre-processor, so the question:

How do you include a stylesheet using drupal_add_css() for specific versions of IE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I Found the solution in the comments on the drupal documentation for [drupal_add_css()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7):

```
drupal_add_css(
  path_to_theme() . '/less/ie.less',
  array(
    'browsers' => array(
      'IE' => 'lte IE 9',
      '!IE' => FALSE
    )
  )
);
```

Using this resulted in the LESS file being compiled by the LESS pre-processor, and the style was included within `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` comment tags.

Comment: Wait. So you're telling me there's an automatic LESS pre-processor for Drupal? Yes there is. Awesome. That's 2 answers in one my friend. Thanks. Link: https://drupal.org/project/less